# $wpdb->get_results with variable

Tags: wordpress

The code below causes this error when I save a page:
Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.

if I replace the active query with the one that is commented out the process produces the expected - though not the desired result.

```
function jma_ghb_clear_transients_save_post($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $plugin_options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_jma_ghb_component%forpost'{$post_id} OR option_name LIKE '_transient_jma_ghb_component'{$post_id}'%'");

    /*$plugin_options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_jma_ghb_component%'");*/

    foreach ($plugin_options as $option) {
        delete_option($option->option_name);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'jma_ghb_clear_transients_save_post');
```

so what am I doing wrong with {$post_id}  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cause the error because your put single quotes **'** in wrong position.

Correct your single quote position to somthing like this and error will be fixed.

```
$plugin_options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_jma_ghb_component%forpost{$post_id}' OR option_name LIKE '_transient_jma_ghb_component{$post_id}%'");
```